# Change maxlength in django cms

Tags: django, django-cms

Good day. I just want to change maxlength of meta_description in Django CMS, so I find titlemodels.py in .virtualenv/cms/models, which contain this:

```
meta_description = models.TextField(_("description"), max_length=155, blank=True, null=True,
    help_text=_("The text displayed in search engines."))
```

So I try to change max_length to 255, but it does not work.
And my question is how can i overwrite this prop? How can I do this?

Comment: Have you migrated your database after changing the value?

Comment: Yes, I do. But no changes were detected.

Comment: This model belongs to the main django-cms app, did you target the right app when migrating?